Are there any ways that I can select just the yellow highlight part?

I tried to Alt-LMB and it will select the entire left side of the edge from top to bottom, are there any shortcut I can use to select/ deselect the edge?
Edit: A bit correction on the detail, the yellow highlight specifically means for selecting the red line(seam), when I alt-clicking it, it will select the entire left side of the edge from top to bottom. I just want to select the red line which is on the bottle cap.

Have you tried pressing c in Edit Mode and then you can like paint select it or simply use the Lasso select as shown here

You can also use C and then hold down Shift while painting over selected vertices to deselect them.
